# Send binary structure to kafka with C

Tags: c, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api, kafka-producer-api

I am creating a message system based on kafka which has to to dump in kafka a complex C structure. To begin I am trying to do something simple by creating a simple structure and sending it:

```
struct Points {
   int   x,y;
} points;

struct Points p;

p.x=0;
p.y=0;

size_t len = sizeof(p);
```

In the producer:

```
rd_kafka_produce(rkt, partition,RD_KAFKA_MSG_F_COPY,&p, len,NULL, 0,NULL)
```

In the consumer I define the same structure but then I use:

```
rkmessage = rd_kafka_consume(rkt, partition, 1000);
struct Points* p2=(struct Points*)&(rkmessage->payload);
            printf("Struct p: %d %d\n\n",p2->x,p2->y);
```

But It prints garbage.

i,j were 1,1

% Message (offset 0, 8 bytes):

Message Payload hexdump (8 bytes):

00000000: 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00

Struct p: -469758844 32530

---

i,j were 256,256

% Message (offset 1, 8 bytes):

Message Payload hexdump (8 bytes):

00000000: 80 00 00 00 80 00 00 00

Struct p: -469758810 32530

---

i,j were 4294967295(max int),4294967295(max int)

% Message (offset 2, 8 bytes):

Message Payload hexdump (8 bytes):

00000000: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff

Struct p: -469758776 32530

---

i,j were 0,0

% Message (offset 3, 8 bytes):

Message Payload hexdump (8 bytes):

00000000: 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00

Struct p: -469758742 32530

---

How can I correctly dump and get the structure? I know I may serialize the data but in the future I will have to  send a much more complex opaque structure. Moreover, by serializing it I may use much more memory.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I think `rd_kafka_consume(rkt, partition, 1000)` is already returning a pointer to you so in the below statement you do not need the `&`

```
struct Points* p2=(struct Points*)(rkmessage->payload);
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: actually, `payload` is `(void *)` so this makes sense.

Comment: right. payload is a void pointer so it requires the structure pointer. By reading the data printed by hexdump it is clear that the data are saved correctly. E.g., 01 00 00 00 01 00 00 00 = 1, 1. But p: -469758844 32530 instead looks more like an address. Indeed, by reading the value one after the other only the first part change

Comment: @Silvestro, Could you elaborate what you are getting when you print `struct p` after making the above change?

Comment: How can we decode it if we are using java library for consumer and C as producer?